# Jqgrid validation response goes to both onSucces and On error

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am performing the validation in server side and returning values based on the validation performed. However my control goes to onError function after the on success function.

Below is my code. Kindly requesting for some help.Thanks in advance.

```
 formatoptions: {
            restoreAfterError:false,
            keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
            onEdit: function (rowid) {

                $('#newDetailCodeGroup').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass("btnDisabled").removeClass("btnNormalInactive");
                //alert("in onEdit: rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
            },
            onSuccess: function (jqXHR) {
                $('#newDetailCodeGroup').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass("btnDisabled").removeClass("btnNormalInactive");
                $('input[id*="gs_"]').val("");
                var selRow = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                var errors = jQuery.parseJSON( jqXHR.responseText );
                if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject( errors ))
                {
                    if(errors.groupDesc){
                        jQuery('#' + selRow + '_groupDesc').css({'background':'#fff0f0','border':'1px solid red','color':'red'});
                        jQuery('#' + selRow + '_groupDesc').attr('title',errors.groupDesc);
                    }
                return false;
                }else{
                    $grid.setGridParam({ search: false, postData: { "filters": ""} ,datatype: 'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                }



                // the function will be used as "succesfunc" parameter of editRow function
                // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow)
                /*alert("in onSuccess used only for remote editing:" +
                    "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                    "\n\nWe can verify the server response and return false in case of" +
                    " error response. return true confirm that the response is successful");
                // we can verify the server response and interpret it do as an error
                // in the case we should return false. In the case onError will be called
                return true;*/
            },
            onError: function (rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                $grid.setGridParam({ search: false, postData: { "filters": ""} ,datatype: 'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                // the function will be used as "errorfunc" parameter of editRow function
                // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow)
                // and saveRow function
                // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow)
                /*alert("in onError used only for remote editing:" +
                    "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                    "\nstatus=" + jqXHR.status +
                    "\nstatusText" + jqXHR.statusText +
                    "\n\nWe don't need return anything");*/
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Such behavior corresponds the code of `onSuccess` because you returns `false` from it. You can just returns `false` from `onSuccess` (which corresponds `successfunc` callback of inline editing) if you detect that the server response contains the error. Inside of `onError` (which corresponds `errorfunc` of of inline editing) you should just display the error message decoded from the server response and **not** make `reloadGrid` if you want allow the user to fix the error in the currently editing grid.

By the way it would be more logical to use `reloadGrid` inside of `afterSave` (which corresponds  `aftersavefunc` callback of inline editing) and not inside of `onSuccess`. Moreover I recommend you to place `.trigger("reloadGrid")` inside `setTimeout`. It allows jqGrid to finish standard processing of inline editing and makes `reloadGrid` *after* that.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for the response, So you are telling me, I should write the code in on Error, But I am just returning an HashMap with error values in it, It actually returns with the status 200. Anyways I will Try and see

Comment: @user2375298: The goal of `onSuccess` is to provide the possibility to detect that the response is the error report. It it's so, jqGrid stop the standard processing, the row will be not just saved as typically and the `errorfunc` callback (`onError`) will be invoked. If the server would set some error HTTP status code (400 or higher) then no `successfunc` (`onSuccess`) are need be implemented at all.

Comment: Hi Oleg, But my after save function is not getting triggered from on success. I have performed only the error check inside the on success and wrote the trigger reload in the after save. But its not firing, and the grid remains in edit mode.

Comment: @user2375298: Sorry, but it seems to me that you still don't understand the meaning of the callbacks. `onSuccess` (`successfunc`) can be used to detect error response even if not have error HTTP status code. So `onSuccess` (`successfunc`) should just returns false in case of error and **returns true in case of no error** (I suppose you don't do this). No error means that the server could successfully save the data. So if you don't trigger reloadGrid then all (with exception of sorting) should be OK. If you do need to reload the data you should do this inside of `afterSave` ('aftersavefunc').

Comment: HI oleg, Thanks again, I have done the same. I have returned false, when I have errors and I have returned true when There are no errors. But the reload grid in the after save call function is what not getting triggered.

Comment: thanks oleg, I understood and have implemented it. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @user2375298: You are welcome! If your modified code still not work then **you should append your question with the the current (modified) code**.